# Model ID not being set backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, models

```
userProjects: function(customerid) {

    this.chat();

    App.core.vent.trigger('app:log', 'Controller: "userProjects" route hit.');
    window.customerTransactions = new CustomerTransactionsCollection([], {id:customerid});
    customerTransactions.fetch({
        success: function(transactions) {
            App.data.transactions = transactions;
            var userProjectsView = new UserProjectsView({ collection: customerTransactions });
            $('.dashboard .container').html(userProjectsView.render().$el);
        }
    });

    window.App.router.navigate('/customer/'+customerid);

}
```

The collection looks somewhat like this

```
[
    {"id":"czy3m4","status":"authorized"},
    {"id":"3sjkn8","status":"authorized"},
]
```

Then when I log `App.data.transactions.get('czy3m4')` it is undefined. There is the `cid` from the client, but no `id` from the model itself, in my other collections the id is there.

```
module.exports = CustomerTransactionModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: 'id'
});
```

[image]

**WORKAROUND**

As a workaround I am doing this

```
userProject: function(projectid) {

    console.log(projectid);

    this.chat();

    var thisModel;
    App.data.transactions.each(function(model) {
        if(model.get('id') === projectid) {
            thisModel = model;
        }
    });

    App.core.vent.trigger('app:log', 'Controller: "userProject" route hit.');
    var userProjectView = new UserProjectView({ model: thisModel });
    $('.dashboard .container').html(userProjectView.render().$el);

    window.App.router.navigate('/customer/'+customerid+'/'+projectid);

}
```

Comment: What does the model look like? How about the collection?

Comment: backbone configuration of the models/collection or the json structure? Its pretty much identical to my other model/collection, but for some reason when I log the collection and view the models where you can view the cid there id for the model is not available, it could be because of how I am serving the data, I am rewriting the server.

Comment: Do you have any `parse` methods in your model or collection? Anything else going on in your model or collection? An `idAttribute` setting perhaps? Is that really what the JSON looks like?

Comment: So the main difference is that in order to retrieve projects I have to find the customer in the api by the id, then the project by its id, so the route looks like `/api/customer/12345/project/0987` and in order to get the projects I need to fetch the proper customer first, so in my backbone collection I customize the url route `url: function() {
   return '/api/customer/' + this.id;
 },`

Comment: In order to fetch properly I do this `window.customerTransactions = new CustomerTransactionsCollection([], {id:customerid});` The overall goal is to pull down the specific project model so that I can work with it directly after navigating to it via customer then customers projects collection then the specific model.

Comment: When I log `customerTransactions` (the collection) its all fine, but when going into it further where you can open the model there is no id, just a cid. I am doing a lot of rewriting to better optimize the flow, a lot of it was pulling data from braintree directly, I am trying to work on building my own project data so that I can make things more RESTful.

Comment: All of that should be fine, you're apparently doing the equivalent of [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/6x04ev09/) and that's okay. So is there anything special in your model or collection? What exactly does the JSON look like?

Comment: I got it working now by adding all the braintree data onto my own mongoDB and built my own RESTful api. I dont know why it did that, maybe the braintree json data I was using had something about it, but IDK. The only downside is keeping the data all in sync with eachother, but thats not a huge problem as any changing data would be custom anyways. Thanks for your time!!